# Using Crystal Report elements with VB6.5

Tags: vb6, crystal-reports

I have been searching everywhere but there seem to have nothing about a basic tutorial for beginners for using vb6 with crystal report.

I am in need of help for simple tasks like writing to a text object in a crystal report to connecting to a csv file.

If anyone can point me to the right direction, that would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to work with CSV files is to import it into a MS Access table and then use it with Crystal Reports.

- To import the CSV file into MS Access, check this tutorial
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=azAHgENjE0Q
- To retrieve data from MS Access to Crystal Reports check this
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pdHyReHr1xs

Comment: Hi David, this is definitely useful.

I apologize for asking beginner level questions. But how do I access text objects in crystal report with VB6?

I tried many different things but my report object(CRAXDRT.Report object), doesn't seem to have ReportDefinition. Let's say I created a text10 object in my report, how do I access it from VB6? Or even set its visibility?

Comment: Check this http://devlibrary.businessobjects.com/businessobjectsxir2/en/en/RDC_SDK/rdc_com_dg_doc/doc/rdcsdk_com_doc/RDC_Programming34.html

Comment: And of course there is nothing that you should apologize for, we are all beginners in some fields :)